# How to determine if a RenderFragement has a content

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-server-side, razor-components

I've just built a very simple razor component for templating a page header. Now I've noticed that my condition regarding the ChildComponent != null is always true. Is there a way to check if the ChildContent has any real content defined?

In my example the PageTitleSecondaryRow will always be rendered into my page, even if ChildContent is empty (but it is not NULL). Which Options do I have. As a workaround I will now make an custom RenderFragment property which is null by initialization. But I do not think that this is the final solution.

```
<div class="wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">
    <div class="row" id="PageTitlePrimaryRow">

        <div id="PageTitleIconColumn">
            @(IconMarkup())
        </div>
        <div  id="PageTitleTextColumn">
            <h2>
                @Title
            </h2>
            @if (Elements != null && Elements.Count > 0)
            {
                <TitleBreadcrumbs Elements="@Elements" />
            }
        </div>
        <div  id="PageTitlePostColumn">
        </div>
    </div>
    @if (ChildContent != null )
    {
        <hr />
        <div id="PageTitleSecondaryRow">
            @ChildContent
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: A Render fragment named ChildContent will only be null if you use self-closing syntax `<MyComponent />`

Comment: Ok. Thank you @peter-morris. That is explaining why sometimes the null check behaves like I want it to. Is there any way to access some inner information of a RenderFragment. The only thing I would need to know is there are any component or elements nested within the ChildContent object. My problem is that the ChildContent in my component is passed through from a  parent component. So in the parent there is never a self-closing syntax, because it is treated like simple placeholder.

Comment: There is no way that I know of. You could instead change the name to something other than ChildContent, and then the consumer of the component will need to explicitly include the name of the property, for example <HeaderTemplate> - and that makes it easy to check for if it was added or not (it will be not null)

Answer (score 1):

As Peter Morris said, ChildContent is only null is you use the self-closing syntax `<MyComponent />`. This is because that is the default render fragment any content gets assigned to, even if it's empty content.

It might be advisable to use a different name for your `RenderFragment`. This way if it is null, you know it has not been explicitly set. An additional benefit is that more accurately conveys what the render fragment is about.

Consider you have the following component `MyComponent.razor`:

```
@if (ListItems != null) 
{
    <ul>
        <li> default item </li>
        @ListItems
    </ul>
}
else 
{
    <p>alternative content</p>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ListItems { get; set; }
}
```

By having a different name for the RenderFragment, you have to explicity set it when using this component. This catches the unintended cases where ChildContent might result in empty html:

```
@* displays only the alternative content *@
<MyComponent></MyComponent>

@* displays the ul element *@
<MyComponent>
    <ListItems>
        <li> other item </li>
    </ListItems>
</MyComponent>
```

It's basically the same, just a different name for the parameter. This prevents Blazor from assuming anything between the opening an closing belongs inside the ChildContent whenever you do not use the self-closing syntax.